# Testing someone else's app on device

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I am working on an app with some other people online and I am having issues trying to run it on my device. Works fine in the simulator but not on devices.

I tried changes the team name from theirs to mine, and I have all of the code signing set to iOS Developer. The provisioning profiles are set to automatic.

When I try to run the app, I get the error: `None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified entitlements: com.apple.security.application-groups.`

Anyone know what I can do to allow me to test it on my device?

Comment: Did you check both Project and Targets?

Comment: Yeah. Both set to 'iOS Developer' and 'Automatic'.

Comment: @pandarencodemaster I pasted the wrong error message. I've updated my question with the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

The app has an app extension entitlement that does not match your team ID.

In Xcode, select the app target.  Select Capabilities.  Scroll down to App Groups.

Answer (score 1):

select the app target -- >Select Capabilities--> App Groups.